# Angular MatDialog open component throught dynamic import

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to open a component in angular using matdialog. My goal is to import the component inside the method because the component is huge and rarely used. The problem is when I load it as in the following code example, I can't access the MatDialogRef anymore and the providers (a view services) won't work anymore. My code currently looks like this:

```
import { Component, inject, Injector, createNgModule, createComponent } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-testA',
    templateUrl: './testA.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./testA.component.scss'],
})
export class TestAComponent {

    private injector = inject(Injector);
    private dialog = inject(MatDialog);

       
    async open() {
        const { TestModule } = await import('testB.module');
        const ref = createNgModule(TestModule, this.injector);

        const { TestComponent } = await import('testB.component');
        const componentRef = createComponent(TestComponent, {
            environmentInjector: ref.injector,
            elementInjector: this.injector,
        });

        this.dialog.open(componentRef.componentType);
    }
}
```

The error in the console look like this

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(TestBModule)[MatDialogRef -> MatDialogRef -> MatDialogRef -> MatDialogRef -> MatDialogRef]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!

Does anyone have any idea what I did wrong? Btw, I am using Angular version 16+.

Comment: is MatDialogModule imported in the Module declaring TestAComponent?

Comment: Yes i imported MatDialogModule in TestAModule and TestBModule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution how to fix this.
In the dialog component where I create the component, I just need to add this code and everything works fine.

```
const ngModuleRef = createNgModule(PdfViewerModule, this.injector);
    
const dynamicComponentInjector = Injector.create({
        providers: [
          // YOUR PROVIDERS
        ],
        parent: ngModuleRef.injector
      });

const pdf = this.container.createComponent(TestCComponent, { injector: dynamicComponentInjector });
```